# Calling a function within a function (invoke) in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm automating some processes within Google Apps Script.

I have created a few functions that are currently independent from each other. 
However now, I want to regroup them so's they are triggered within the "master" function.

```
function master(){
     // code that imports data from a form and organises it
     runMeAfterMaster();
  }


function runMeAfterMaster(){
    // code that should run after master
}
```

Both are in the same script file, both work independently but I can't seem to just be able to "invoke" or call my other function within the master one.

Please Help!

Comment: hi Tony, could you please elaborate what do you mean "can't invoke". What error you've received?

Comment: You have to check master function is invoked or not ., once master function called other function also star working .

Comment: Hi Guys! Thank you gents!! Eugene: by "i can't invoke" i'm talking about calling the function runMeAfterMaster() within the master() funciton. But my syntax doesn't run it. @Thom: yes, I run the function master but the runMeAfterMaster() function doesn't run within it. Don't think its a scope problem as both functions are in the same script file. Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue when my function names started with lower case letters.

the error I got was:
TypeError: randomNumber is not a function

my code:

```
/*
goal of the script is to highlight project rotators
*/

function HightlightProject() 
{

  // get random number
  var randomNumber =  randomNumber();


}

function randomNumber()
{
  // get cell from certain spread sheet
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("fundation rotator!B7");
  
  // random number
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  
  // set random number
  cell.setValue(number);
}
```

if I capitalize randomNumber to RandomNumber, the function names turn pink, and it works.

```
/*
goal of the script is to highlight project rotators
*/

function HightlightProject() 
{

  // get random number
  var randomNumber =  RandomNumber();


}

function RandomNumber()
{
  // get cell from certain spread sheet
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("fundation rotator!B7");
  
  // random number
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  
  // set random number
  cell.setValue(number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote is ok runMeAfterMaster look to be invoked, I suppose your problem is elsewhere have you decorated your functions with Logger.log?
eg:

```
function master(){
     // code that imports data from a form and organises it
     Logger.log("I'm in master now");
     runMeAfterMaster();
     Logger.log("still in master but after calling runMeAfterMaster");
  }


function runMeAfterMaster(){
    Logger.log("I'm in runMeAfterMaster now");
    // code that should run after master

    Logger.log("getting out of runMeAfterMaster");
}
```

if you can't use Logger.log because the function is triggered automatically (and you can't have a look at the logs) yoo can replace it by your own loggin function that write everything in a spreadsheet:

```
function logit(message) {
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET_ID").getActiveSheet().appendRow([new Date(),message]);
}
```

then it will become:

```
function master(){
     // code that imports data from a form and organises it
     logit("I'm in master now");
     runMeAfterMaster();
     logit("still in master but after calling runMeAfterMaster");
  }


function runMeAfterMaster(){
    logit("I'm in runMeAfterMaster now");
    // code that should run after master

    logit("getting out of runMeAfterMaster");
}
```

Comment: Thank you Harold for your answer!

Comment: How did you know I couldn't debug/log?

Answer (score 0):

Harold's tips put me on the right path. The path to testing things out.

I placed my code in a code editor (in my case Brackets) and ran it through JSLint. To find any errors.

No errors there, even though the curly bracket at the end of the function name was red. It turns out over 100 lines of code in google apps and the curly bracket turns red. Under 100 lines you're good to go!

Unfortunately i couldn't debug.

So i decided to make it simpler and call both functions within a new one. That didn't work...and I still ignore why.

```
 function MasterOfAll(){
    Master();
    runAfterMaster();
 }
```

Second thing I did was to simply regroup both code of each function in a new one and call it. That worked.

```
function MasterOfAll(){
    //Code from the Master function.
    //Code from the runAfterMasterFunction.
}
```

Needless to say, I'm not a big fan of this solution (unclear, messy) but it works!

Comment: your trouble is quite unexplicable as it. if you don't give us more code I suppose that we won't be able to help you more here